# How to add list as a parameter to sqlQuery in grails?

Tags: grails, groovy

I am writing a query and want to set parameter which is a list of strings.

My query is

```
def strQuery = """SELECT * from user u where u.status in (?)"""

def session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()

def resultList = session.createSQLQuery(strQuery)
        .setParameter(0, UserStatus.List)
        .list();
```

Where

```
public enum UserStatus {
    ACTIVE("Active"),
    ARCHIVE("Archived"),

    public static final List<UserStatus> List = [ACTIVE,ARCHIVED]

}
```

but I am getting an exception

```
ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter  - ERROR: operator does not exist: character varying = bytea
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To bind a list, you will have to use [setParameterList](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/Query.html#setParameterList(java.lang.String,%20java.util.Collection)) with named parameter.

`setParameter` is only for single value.

```
def strQuery = """SELECT * from user u where u.status in (:statusList)"""

def session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()

def resultList = session.createSQLQuery(strQuery)
    .setParameterList('statusList', UserStatus.List)
    .list();
```

Comment: This solves my problem. But there was only 1 issue. My list was [ACTIVE,ARCHIVED] & I had to convert it to ['ACTIVE','ARCHIVED'] cz it was giving exception org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: character varying = bytea